# Why is the value and the times which the function is called different, and how does recursion work in this code?

Tags: python

Updated: May I know how recursion works for this similar code?

```
def fib( n ):
    global cnt
    cnt += 1 #global cnt is assigned and changed
    if n <= 2:
        return 1
    return fib( n - 1 ) + fib( n - 2 )

cnt = 0
print(fib( 10 ))
print("fib is called", cnt, "times") #109 times!
```

Old question:

```
def power_of_two(n):
    global cnt
    cnt += 1
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return 2 * power_of_two(n-1)
cnt = 0
print(power_of_two(3))
print("power_of_two is called", cnt, "times")
```

> Question: What is the value of cnt and how many times is the function power_of_two() called when the code above is executed?
>
> A. 8, 4 times
> B. 4, 3 times
> C. 6, 4 times
> D. 3, 3 times

I ran the code and it shows that cnt is 4, so should it be answer B?
But for answer B, it says that the code is called 3 times but shouldn't it be 4?
If it is 3, may I know why then?
I thought of choosing answer A too since it makes more sense, but it asks for the value of cnt but not the value of (power_of_two(3)).
Or did I misintepret the question/ did my teacher write the question wrongly?
I know this is a basic programming question but thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure what I should clarify (?) since it is already the whole problem(?) sorry I am new here

Comment: And thanks for the edit, sorry for wrong formatting

Comment: Welcome ! do you know how to run a [python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) ?

Comment: You increment `cnt` before the 0 check.  At the `n==0` check:  `n=3, cnt = 1, return 2*`,  `n=2, cnt = 2, return 2*2*`,  `n=1, cnt = 3, return 2*2*2*`,  `n=0, cnt = 4`, returned value is `2*2*2*1 = 8`

Comment: The function is called 4 times and the result is 8 (2**3) so what's the problem? The question is badly worded. The value of *cnt* and the number of times the function is called are one and the same thing

Comment: Question: What is the value of cnt and how many times is the function power_of_two() called when the code above is executed?                                                                            A. 8, 4 times
B. 4, 3 times
C. 6, 4 times
D. 3, 3 times                                                                                                                               Seems that the four options which my teacher has given me are wrong(?) As cnt is 4 and the function is called 4 times

Comment: @SIGHUP Yeah I know that but there is no answer with 4, 4 times. Perhaps I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Yes, it seems like your teacher wanted to ask for the value that the function returns and not the value of `cnt` (which equals the number of times the function is called). Then, "A" would be the correct answer since 2**3=8.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :), I guess my teacher was asking for the result instead of value of cnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be 4 times for `n=3`, Steps for your code.

for `n==3` your `cnt ==1` `return 2*` #Recursion step 1

for `n==2` it will be `cnt ==2` `return 2*2*` #Recursion step 2

for `n==1` it will be `cnt==3` `return 2*2*2*` #Recursion step 3

and for last step  is the stop recursion with  `if n==0` statement, so `cnt==4` `return 2*2*2*1` #Recursion step 4

**result will be A) 8, 4 times**

Comment: Thanks `def fib( n ):
    global cnt
    cnt += 1 #global cnt is assigned and changed
    if n <= 2:
        return 1
    return fib( n - 1 ) + fib( n - 2 )

cnt = 0
print(fib( 10 ))
print("fib is called", cnt, "times") #109 times!` But may I know how does recursion work for this similar code?

Comment: because u'll do recursion for each steps for avoiding this problem implement memorization. ``def fib(n, memo={}):
    global cnt
    cnt += 1  
    if n <= 2:
        return 1
    if n not in memo:
        memo[n] = fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo)
    return memo[n]

cnt = 0
print(fib(12))
print("fib is called", cnt, "times")`` it will avoid to repeat recursions. So it will avoid to repeat same recursions. You will have 21 times if u use memorization otherwise it will be 287 times.

Comment: Thank you, but I just wanna ask why the output of my original code (see updated code) is 109 times (cnt = 109) and the result is 55. Is there possibly a way to verify this without having to run the code?

Comment: BTW, the technique is called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) (without an 'r')

Comment: fib(10) will call fib(9) and (fib8) fib(9 will call fib(8) and fib(7) also fib(8) will call fib(7) and fib(6) it will be like keep goin like that

Comment: @Friedrich I missing that always while I writing

Comment: @MuhammedSamedÖzmen thank you so much for the clear explanation (though the other one was deleted?), but I am not too sure why cnt is 109 (how do I calculate it manually)?

Comment: @blackstar 
manually fib 3 will 3 times fib 4 will be 5 times fib 5 will be 9 times fib(n) times = fib(n-1) times + fib(n-2) times +1  so u can say 1 1 3 5 9 15 25 41 67 109 177 ... with that u can calculate manually. +1 mean is u calling itself and it will count 1 step.

Comment: @MuhammedSamedÖzmen Hmm but if I do this for 10, result for fib(n-1) will be (9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1) and fib(n-2) will be (8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1), adding them up then +1 becomes 81 (not 109(?))

Comment: @blackstar for fib(3) it will be 3 steps for fib4 it will be 5 steps fib5 will be 9 fib6 will be 15  fib 7 will be 25 fib8 will be 41 fib9 will be 67 and fib10 will be 109. So fib10 it willbe ( fib(9) which is 67 and fib8 will be 41steps and call fib10 itself 1 steps totally 109)

Comment: Oh I understand now thanks, so does it mean I have to calculate it step by step? Or is there possibly an equation for it

Comment: Not sure if there is any formula. I just find that equation while examining the result.@blackstar